# What happens to non-serializable super class instance fields after deserialization while subclass is serializable

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, serializable

I have been digging a lot on this, but did not find any proper explanation. What would be the state of instance fields of class `A` after deserialization?

Note that associated entity `C` is `Serializable` but `A` is not.

```
class A {
   int a;
   String sa;
   C c;
}
class B extends A implements Serializable {
   int b;
   String sb;
}
class c implements Serializable {
   int c;
   String sc;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What happens to them is whatever the accessible npo-args constructor does in the non-serializable superclass. In your case nothing, so they assume their default values: zero, false, or null.